# How to extract 'format string' of a 'date string' in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, format

Date-Time is read from external resource and stored in $dt, And it could be in any *valid* PHP Date-Time format (valid means date-time is already formated by a string containing letters described [here on php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)).

What I need to do is to get format of the date-time string, So after manipulating the date to system needs, I can reformat it to the same string and store it in database. Simply put: do opposite of DateTime::format method

Is there any particular method which extracts 'format string' of a formated date-time? or an available code?

Comment: Note that formatted dates may not contain enough information to deduce their formatting: `01/02/03` could be month-day-year or day-month-year or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, as the formatted dates can not contain enough information. You will have to write some set of regexp to match your formats which are really used as your inputs - one by one.

Comment: certainly it's possible, if not precise. If strtotime() et al can detect a date in an arbitrary string, why couldn't we simply invert the logic?

Answer (score 0):

You could take them all to a unix timestamp and then use date to get a standardised form. Or you could standardise your input in the first place (which is usually the easier option - because error catching is going to be a mare!)

```
\\$dt your datetime input
$timestring = strtotime($dt);
$datetime = date("H:i:s j M Y", $timestring);
```

Of course, you might get some funny outputs from `strtotime` if your inputs are weird.